# Spring not injecting @Value from Properties file in some classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-boot

In the following Spring Boot application, the @Value annotation is succeeding in the WebSecurityConfig class, but not in the FileSystemUpload class. In the FileSystemUpload class, the value (testing) results in null using the same properties file that WebSecurityConfig is using.

Application.java

```
package com.project;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("${project.properties}")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java (where @Value injection is working correctly)

```
package com.project.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static String ldapUser;
    @Value("${ldap.user: user}")
    public void setPrivateLdapUser(String privateName) {
    ldapUser = privateName;
    }  
    ...
}
```

FileSystemUpload.java (where testing is not getting injected and is null)

```
package com.project.service;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class FileSystemUpload {

    @Value("${testing}")
    String testing;

    ...
}
```

utility.properties
    testing=thisisatest

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer this question myself. It turns out, the class FileSystemUpload was being referenced like a normal Java object:

```
FileSystemUpload upload = new FileSystemUpload()
```

It should have been using Spring annotations to reference the class (@Autowired). Once I converted the references to the class to @Autowired and removed the creation of the new FileSystemUpload class, all the @Value injection in that class worked.